# HTC One issues with ACTION_CALL intent

Tags: android, android-intent, htcsense

I released an app on the app store that seems to run into problems with the HTC One. As soon as the app is opened, the app execute an intent to make a phone call, ACTION_CALL. I have a call intent but it's accessed after a button press followed by accessing the location services and then a 5 second sleep() call. But with the HTC Sense, it goes straight to the call, without even showing the layouts. I have a Galaxy S3 running 4.3 and the app's target SDK is 19, and the app is working without a hitch.

Why is this happening? Does the HTC Sense have issues with calling intents? Is there anyway of stopping the intent from occuring, sort of like a signalHandler if it's an HTC Sense device?

HTC Sense 5.0, Android: 4.3

Code (Activity that calls phone intent):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    x=9;
    final TextView localTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addr);
    LocationManager localLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    localLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
    localLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000L, 10.0F, new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location paramAnonymousLocation) {
            double d1 = paramAnonymousLocation.getLatitude();
            double d2 = paramAnonymousLocation.getLongitude();
            Geocoder localGeocoder = new Geocoder(Test.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List localList = localGeocoder.getFromLocation(d1, d2, 1);
                if (localList.size() == 1) {
                    Address localAddress = (Address) localList.get(0);
                    Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[3];
                    if (localAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) ;
                    for (String str1 = localAddress.getAddressLine(0); ; str1 = "") {
                        arrayOfObject[0] = str1;
                        arrayOfObject[1] = localAddress.getAddressLine(1);
                        arrayOfObject[2] = localAddress.getCountryName();
                        String str2 = String.format("%s, %s, %s", arrayOfObject);
                        localTextView.setText(str2);
                        if(x==9){
                        Test.this.waititout();}
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException localIOException) {
                localIOException.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
                localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String paramAnonymousString) {
            localTextView.setText("TURN ON GPS DUMMY");
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String paramAnonymousString) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String paramAnonymousString, int paramAnonymousInt, Bundle paramAnonymousBundle) {
        }
    });
}

public void waititout()
        throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Date localDate = new Date();
                Calendar localCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                localCalendar.setTime(localDate);
                int i = localCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(4000L);
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");
                localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:17325450900"));
                Test.this.startActivity(localIntent);

                return;
            } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
                System.out.println(localInterruptedException);
            }
        }
    }
            .start();
}
```

Comment: You actually display a message to end users that reads, "TURN ON GPS DUMMY"?  Too funny.

Comment: I don't see any onClick event, just that `x=9` is put before the location listener, then a check for `x==9` to trigger the phone call if other conditions are met. Perhaps something is missing from the above or a condition you wanted to have is not present?

Comment: @JeremyMiller Yeah so basically this activity accesses the location via GPS, displays the address, waits 3 seconds, and then starts the call intent. The OnClick event is just an intent to this activity, it's literally Intent LocalIntent = new Intent(this, Test.class)

Comment: @JeremyMiller The condition is there to try to avoid teh bug, it works perfectly on my S3 so the logic isn't a problem. IT just spazzes out on my friend's HTC One and I'm not sure why

Comment: OK.  Sorry, but I am at a loss then and my phone is the HTC DNA, so not helpful.  The code above, though is reached only through the intent, so makes me wonder if there's another means of creating the intent -- that's just a hypothetical wild guess, though, in an attempt to help.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Would you mind installing the app to see if it works? It's free w/o ads or any other bloat, and called RUDrunk

Comment: Installed on HTC DNA with Android 4.4.2 and HTC Sense 5.5.  No calls placed, so presumably functioning fine on my device.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Ok col. Thank you so much for downloading it, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JeremyMiller Does everything else look fine? Do the two big buttons appear, does the "Maybe" test work?

Comment: There were 2 big buttons.  I didn't do any testing of anything other than opening it and seeing if there was a call placed. Sorry.

Comment: @JeremyMiller All good bro, this is my first app so I'm a little nervous. Thanks for the help dude